# android apps unfortunately has stopped when using intent to an activity with listView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

Whenever I use intent to an activity that has listView or Spinner, the application keep saying "Unfortunately the app has stopped", I'm still new to it. Can anybody tell me how to fix this?
And here's the logcat:

```
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:524)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:377)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2027)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.AmigoResources.loadDrawable(AmigoResources.java:204)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
11-18 13:55:13.603 3768-3768/com.example.ridha.kuda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:98)
```

There are still more of them.
And this is the java code of the activity I want to go to:

```
   public class ViewMyOrderController extends AppCompatActivity {
     String[] orderTitles;
     int[] indicator = {R.drawable.circle, R.drawable.circle2,  R.drawable.circle3, R.drawable.circle3 };
     ListView orderList;
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_my_order_controller);
      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

      Resources res= getResources();
      orderTitles=res.getStringArray(R.array.orderTitle);
      orderList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
      MyOrderAdapter adapter= new    MyOrderAdapter(this,orderTitles,indicator);
      orderList.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
    class MyOrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
      Context context;
      int [] images;
      String [] titlesArray;
      MyOrderAdapter(Context c, String[] orderTitles, int[] orderImage){
        super(c,R.layout.my_order_rows,R.id.textView16, orderTitles);
        this.context=c;
        this.images=orderImage;
        this.titlesArray=orderTitles;
      }
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_order_rows,parent,false);

        ImageView orderImage= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
        TextView orderTitle= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView16);


        orderImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        orderTitle.setText(titlesArray[position]);

        return row;
     }
  }
```

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` - Your images are too big.

Answer (score 0):

try `largeHeap="true"` in Manifest

and compress all images what u r using in `Listview`
.

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: under application tag just write  android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: Couldn't find the largeHeap="true" in manifest android-studio 1.4, and the images I used are < 20KB.
When I check to the bitmapFactory class, I found an error in the traceBegin(). It says couldn't resolve method. I don't know what to do or install cause it seems there's something missing in my android-studio

Comment: I use android studio 1.4 , I try to look for "largeHeap" in the manifest but couldn't find it.Do I have to add it by myself? on which part?(the activity, the permission tag or the application)

The images that I used are < 20KB in size,so I don't really think it's the memory problem eventhough it says so.
When I check the error class shown in the logCat, I found errors in the Bitmap class, one of them says that the "traceBegin" method can't be resolved.

Comment: you have to add that in manifest under application tag as i mentioned.

Comment: thanks guys for the time you spent helping me, I found out the error was in the trace class because it only supports for API 18 above, I used API 15.